# 2 dropdown lists connected to each-other (the 2nd one depends from the first)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to solve an exercise with these demands : "Create a HTML page also using javascript who contains a dropdown list where u choose the State and another dropdown list is filled dynamically with cities belonging to that Country.
I have seen other similar questions and applied the suggestions but it still doesnt seem to work (the 2nd dropdown list stays empty).

```
 <html>
    <head>

     <script type = "text/javascript">

    function update()
{
var albania = ["Tirana","Durres","Vlore","Shkoder"];
var kosovo = ["Prishtina","Mitrovica","Peje","Gjakove"];
var germany = ["Berlin","Frankfurt","Hannover","Bonn"];

var  countries = document.getElementById("1");
var cities = document.getElementById("2");
var selected = countries.options[countries.selectedIndex].value;

if(selected=="1"){
for(var i = 0; i < albania.length; i++) {
    var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
    opt1.innerHTML = albania[i];
    opt1.value = albania[i];
    cities.appendChild(opt1);
}
}
else if(selected=="2")
{
for(var j = 0; j < kosovo.length; j++) {
    var opt2 = document.createElement('option');
    opt2.innerHTML = kosovo[j];
    opt2.value = kosovo[j];
    cities.appendChild(opt2);
}
}
else if(selected=="3")
{
for(var k = 0; k < germany.length; k++) {
    var opt3 = document.createElement('option');
    opt3.innerHTML = germany[k];
    opt3.value = germany[k];
    cities.appendChild(opt3);
}
}
 else
var t =0;
 }
    </script>

    </head>

  <body>

    <p><select  id= "1" onchange="update()">
       <option selected = "selected" >Select Country</option>
       <option value="1">Albania</option>
       <option value="2">Kosovo</option>
       <option value="3">Germany</option>
       </select>
       </p>

    <p><select  id="2">
       <option selected = "selected" ></option>


    </body>
    </html>`"
```

Comment: You are heavily using DOM API, which will slow down the performance of the page, and use "createTextNode" function instead of "innerHTML" when you are creating option text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sd8d4p8a/2/) as per your requirement.

Javascript :

```
var albania = ["Tirana","Durres","Vlore","Shkoder"];
var kosovo = ["Prishtina","Mitrovica","Peje","Gjakove"];
var germany = ["Berlin","Frankfurt","Hannover","Bonn"];


document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("change", function(e){
        var select2 = document.getElementById("2");
        select2.innerHTML = "";
        var aItems = [];
    if(this.value == "2"){
        aItems = kosovo;
    } else if (this.value == "3") {
        aItems = germany;
    } else if(this.value == "1") {
        aItems = albania;
    }
    for(var i=0,len=aItems.length; i<len;i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value= (i+1);
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(aItems[i]);
        option.appendChild(textNode);
        select2.appendChild(option);
    }

}, false);
```

HTML :

```
<p><select  id= "1">
       <option selected = "selected" >Select Country</option>
       <option value="1">Albania</option>
       <option value="2">Kosovo</option>
       <option value="3">Germany</option>
       </select>
       </p>

    <p><select  id="2">
        <option selected = "selected" ></option></select></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>
        <select id="country" onchange="update()">
            <option selected="selected">Select Country</option>
            <option value="1">Albania</option>
            <option value="2">Kosovo</option>
            <option value="3">Germany</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <select id="city">
            <option selected="selected">Select City</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function update()
        {
            var albania=["Tirana", "Durres", "Vlore", "Shkoder"];
            var kosovo=["Prishtina", "Mitrovica", "Peje", "Gjakove"];
            var germany=["Berlin", "Frankfurt", "Hannover", "Bonn"];
            var countries=document.getElementById("country");
            var cities=document.getElementById("city");
            var selected=countries.value;
            var html='<option selected="selected">Select City</option>';
            if(selected === "1")
            {
                for(var i=0; i < albania.length; i++)
                {
                    html+='<option value="' + albania[i] + '">' + albania[i] + '</option>';
                }
            }
            else if(selected === "2")
            {
                for(var j=0; j < kosovo.length; j++)
                {
                    html+='<option value="' + kosovo[j] + '">' + kosovo[j] + '</option>';
                }
            }
            else if(selected === "3")
            {
                for(var k=0; k < germany.length; k++)
                {
                    html+='<option value="' + germany[k] + '">' + germany[k] + '</option>';
                }
            }
            cities.innerHTML=html;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function update() {
//Add additional country with id and city array
        var countriesArray = [
                ["albania", "1", ["Tirana", "Durres", "Vlore", "Shkoder"]],
                ["kosovo", "2", ["Prishtina", "Mitrovica", "Peje", "Gjakove"]],
                ["germany", "3", ["Berlin", "Frankfurt", "Hannover", "Bonn"]]

        ];
//Get country dropdown
        var countries = document.getElementById("1");

//Get city dropdown
        var cities = document.getElementById("2");

//Get country selected item
        var selected = countries.options[countries.selectedIndex].value;

//If country is not "Select Country"
        if (selected != "0") {

//Clear previous cities - this can be moved outside of if condition, and remove the else, if wanted.
            Clear(cities);

//For each country, if it is selected, populate the cities dropdown with its associated city array.

            var country;
            var cityArray;
            for (var i = 0; i < countriesArray.length; i++) {

//Get country
                country = countriesArray[i];
                if (country[1] == selected) {

//Get city array
                    cityArray = country[2];

//Populate options with city array
                    for (var p = 0; p < cityArray.length; p++) {
                        var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
                        opt1.innerHTML = cityArray[p];
                        opt1.value = cityArray[p];
                        cities.appendChild(opt1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Clear(cities);
        }
    }

    function Clear(ctrl)
    {
        ctrl.options.length = 1;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p>
     <select id="1" onchange="update()">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
        <option value="1">Albania</option>
        <option value="2">Kosovo</option>
        <option value="3">Germany</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p>
    <select id="2">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select City</option>
    </select>
</p>
```